# MVC and Bootstrap 4: change style of generated button tag with DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-4, html-helper, bootstrap-select

In my ASP.NET MVC Core web app, I generate a dropdown via the following code in a .cshtml file:

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedType,
        new SelectList(Model.Types, "TypeId", "Name"), "Select one...",
        new
        {
            @class = "selectpicker",
            data_show_subtext = "false",
            data_live_search = "true"
        })
</div>
```

I'm using the `bootstrap-select` library too, btw.

This generates the following HTML when I inspect the page in Chrome:

```
<div>
<div class="dropdown bootstrap-select">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-show-subtext="false" data-val="true" data-val-required="Type is required."
        id="SelectedType" name="SelectedType" tabindex="-98">
        <!-- option tags omitted -->
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-light" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="SelectedType" title="X">
        <div class="filter-option">
            <div class="filter-option-inner">
                <div class="filter-option-inner-inner">X</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu " role="combobox">
        <div class="bs-searchbox">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-label="Search">
        </div>
        <div class="inner show" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu inner show"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

All is good. However, with Bootstrap 4 I find myself needing to change the `btn-light` class to `btn-outline-secondary` in the `<button>` tag.

**How do I do this via the HtmlHelper `DropDownListFor` method?**

I can of course do some post-rendering stuff in JS like

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").removeClass("btn-light").addClass("btn-outline-secondary");
```

...but that seems like a fallback option and it's not optimal.